# WM_PRINTCLIENT to BMP coming out all black

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

I am new to working with MFC and bitmaps. I have a `HWND`, which I want to print onto a bitmap using `WM_PRINTCLIENT`. This is what I have thus far:

EDIT:

```
CRect rcWindow;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcWindow);         

HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);          
HDC hBitmapDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rcWindow.Width(), rcWindow.Height());             

SelectObject(hBitmapDC, hBitmap);

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, (WPARAM)hBitmapDC, PRF_CHILDREN | PRF_CLIENT | PRF_NONCLIENT);                                

CImage image;
image.Attach(hBitmap);
image.Save(_T("C:\\Test.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```

This however results in a bitmap that is all black. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're creating a compatible bitmap for the DC, selecting it into the DC, then printing it... without actually putting anything INTO the bitmap...

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```
    HDC hBitmapDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rcWindow.Width(), rcWindow.Height());
    ::SelectObject(hBitmapDC, hBitmap);

    // Blt the existing background into the bitmap DC
    ::BitBlt(hBitmapDC, 
             0, 0, rcWindow.Width(), rcWindow.Height(), 
             hDC, rcWindow.left, rcWindow.top, SRCCOPY);
```

Don't forget to delete the bitmap object using ::DeleteObject, and the bitmap DC using DeleteDC, when  you've finished with them...

Hope this helps

Comment: I just remembered why I wanted to use `WM_PRINTCLIENT`. I need in my bitmap the hidden parts of the client area as well as all that is visible. How would I adapt your answer to use the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` mesage?

Comment: I've never used WM_PRINTCLIENT myself I'm afraid; but it looks like it just draws the visible client area. I'd adjust the params to BitBlt to take into account the entire area rather than just the visible area. So rcWindow.Width() and rcWindow.Height() will become the width & height of the full area you want to draw, and rcWindow.left / rcWindow.top will become the negative offset of the window client's 'viewport' onto the full area. Of course your window painting routine will need to ensure that it doesn't clip to the client rect when you do this...