# How to get image data of Edit Control

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I have a scrollable Rich edit control. Is it possible to generate an image of the entire text that is in the control.

I tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
but that only gives me an image of the text currently showing on the screen, and doesn't include the text out of view (since it's scrollable).

Any ideas? I have access to the controls Handle and message pump, WM_PAINT messages etc. Thanks!

Edit: I should mention, It's a rich edit control, so the image data should have the formatting and color data also.

Comment: Paint the text directly to a device context

Comment: @david Thanks David, actually it's a rich edit, would the DC show the formatting and colors?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read the title but missed the detail that this is rich edit

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but I asked a fairly similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135738/wm-printclient-to-bmp-coming-out-all-black. If you read the last comment on the accepted solution Liam proposes playing around with the parameters passed into BitBlt to get the stuff that is out of view. I haven't tried it myself yet, but maybe it will work for you?

Comment: Looking at the print/print preview support may be helpfull

Comment: See [How to Print the Contents of Rich Edit Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787875.aspx) for sample code that prints the contents of a Rich Edit Control to a device context. You can create a meta device context calling [CreateEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183498.aspx) if you wish to store the image data to a file.